# PHP sessions not loading on live version of site

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, session-storage

We have been building a site on a localhost up till now, and sessions have all been working fine for all aspects of the site. Once we put it up live, the sessions no longer work, and when I check the resources it says there is no session data or cookies at all.

the site is http://www.welearn.ca

is there any difference between the two platforms that could cause issues?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: service provider of your domain

Comment: hosting space provider??